# Error: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, nsarray

I am a rookie in Xcode and I have been using the UITableViewController which shows this error.

**This is the error message:**
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c91012 0x10cee7e 0x1c330b4 0x36d0 0xc58d5 0xc5b3d 0xacce83 0x1c50376 0x1c4fe06 0x1c37a82 0x1c36f44 0x1c36e1b 0x1beb7e3 0x1beb668 0x1665c 0x2132 0x2065)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)

**This is my code:**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


 if (indexPath.row == 0) {

    NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost:8888/GetDetail.php?choice=row0"];
    NSArray *arrayImagesNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];


    arrayDataFromServer2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSEnumerator *enumForNames = [arrayImagesNames objectEnumerator];

    id objName;

    while ( objName = [enumForNames nextObject]) {
        [arrayDataFromServer2 addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:objName, @"name", nil]];
    }

    NSString *nn = [[arrayDataFromServer2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];

    row1 = [nn intValue];
    NSLog(@"%d", row1);

    CompanyProfileViewController *profile = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Profile"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:profile animated:YES];

    profile.profileid = row1;
    NSLog(@"%d", profile.profileid);
}

if (indexPath.row == 1) {

    NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost:8888/GetDetail.php?choice=row1"];
    NSArray *arrayImagesNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];


    arrayDataFromServer2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSEnumerator *enumForNames = [arrayImagesNames objectEnumerator];

    id objName;

    while (objName = [enumForNames nextObject]) {
        [arrayDataFromServer2 addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:objName, @"name", nil]];
    }

    NSString *nn = [[arrayDataFromServer2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];

    row1 = [nn intValue];
    NSLog(@"%d", row1);

    CompanyProfileViewController *profile = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Profile"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:profile animated:YES];

    profile.profileid = row1;
    NSLog(@"%d", profile.profileid);
}

if (indexPath.row == 2) {

    NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost:8888/GetDetail.php?choice=row2"];
    NSArray *arrayImagesNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];


    arrayDataFromServer2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSEnumerator *enumForNames = [arrayImagesNames objectEnumerator];

    id objName;

    while ( objName = [enumForNames nextObject]) {
        [arrayDataFromServer2 addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:objName, @"name", nil]];
    }

    NSString *nn = [[arrayDataFromServer2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];

    row1 = [nn intValue];
    NSLog(@"%d", row1);

    CompanyProfileViewController *profile = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Profile"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:profile animated:YES];

    profile.profileid = row1;
    NSLog(@"%d", profile.profileid);
}

if (indexPath.row == 3) {

    NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost:8888/GetDetail.php?choice=row3"];
    NSArray *arrayImagesNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];


    arrayDataFromServer2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSEnumerator *enumForNames = [arrayImagesNames objectEnumerator];

    id objName;

    while ( objName = [enumForNames nextObject]) {
        [arrayDataFromServer2 addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:objName, @"name", nil]];
    }

    NSString *nn = [[arrayDataFromServer2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];

    row1 = [nn intValue];
    NSLog(@"%d", row1);

    CompanyProfileViewController *profile = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Profile"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:profile animated:YES];

    profile.profileid = row1;
    NSLog(@"%d", profile.profileid);
 }
}
```

When I click on the second cell (index.row == 1) this error would occur.
I have used breakpoint and the error was on the line:
"NSString *nn = [[arrayDataFromServer2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];"

Please Help!

Comment: Try to figure out why your data source is empty. Learn to read the crash logs.

Comment: Tell us exactly which statement and try to use breakpoint to reach exact location...

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I have used breakpoint and the error was on line "NSString *nn = [[arrayDataFromServer2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];" when I click on the index.row == 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array and you have either 0 or 1 elements in it. Now you are trying to extract 2nd element from it, [0] is first, and [1] is second.

EDIT:

As you are not sure when the array will contain 1 or more objects. Therefore you can use as:

```
NSString *nn=nil;
if([arrayDataFromServer2 count]>1){    
    nn = [[arrayDataFromServer2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
}
```

Comment: I have edited the question to clearer explain the problem. Please Help!

Comment: Another problem came with the code. When I use this code: NSString *nn;
        if([arrayDataFromServer count]>1){
        nn = [[arrayDataFromServer objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
        }
        
        CompanyProfileViewController *profile = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Profile"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:profile animated:YES];
        profile.profileid = [nn intValue];
        NSLog(@"%d", profile.profileid); ---- Is doesn't change the profile.profileid value. Do you have any suggestions for this ?

Comment: am not sure(as this typically an ios logic, and am not much into it), but u r creating an new instance of CompyProfileViwConrlr...

Answer (score 3):

## Swift 4

after more time i am get the love for this Error 
when you use the tableView from the storyboard and implementing in your code :
hint that and compare :
between the number of section and numberOfRowsInSection == storyboard and code

```
 override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 3
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return 1
    }
```